# Can the Recursion Theorem be proved in Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, recursion, foundations, peano-axioms

A recursive function on $\mathbb{N}$ can be defined as follows:

Given an element $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, we can define a function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ as follows:

1. $g(0) = a$
2. $g(n+1) = f(g(n))$

The fact that $g$ exists and is unique can be proved using the **Recursion Theorem** in set theory.

My understanding is that in Peano Arithmetic, it is possible prove the existence of exponentiation using just addition and multiplication, but is it true for any recursively defined function?

In other words, is the existence of addition and multiplication strong enough to prove the existence of any recursive function? i.e can the Recursion Theorem be proved using the **Peano Axioms** (including addition and multiplication)?

**Update:** Since the answers below indicate that this is true, I am looking for an outline of a  proof or a reference that shows that addition and multiplication are powerful enough to define any recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

$PA$ can indeed prove the recursion theorem, although it's a bit of work to formalize it properly since $PA$ doesn't talk directly about functions. It's much better to work in the theory $ACA_0$, a conservative two-sorted extension of $PA$ which *does* talk directly about functions.

---

However, this isn't really the end of the story. It's not that $ACA_0$ proves the *existence* of exponentiation, but rather that PA proves the *totality* of exponentiation. And, in fact, $ACA_0$ does *not* prove the totality of every recursive function! This is a somewhat different issue, and I suspect that this is what you are really interested in.

Comment: Thanks this is interesting. Can you elaborate or provide references that I can read on how one might go about proving the recursion theorem in PA, and and what you mean by *existence* and *totality*?

Comment: @KostubDeshmukh So as I said, even *formulating* the recursion theorem in PA is some work. I would first look at $ACA_0$; Simpson's book "Subsystems of Second-order arithmetic" describes it in detail, and it's not hard to see how the standard proof of the recursion theorem goes through unchanged in $ACA_0$. For $PA$, I don't know of a canonical source, but it's essentially the same: once you state it properly, it follows immediately from induction. (But you need to use $+$ and $\times$ in the process of stating it properly.)